# How to check when a Tween or Transistion has ended, AS3

Tags: flash

I have a white box on a grey background.
When the movieclip starts, it fades in with a Transition.

Simple enough:

```
Obj = new Object();
Obj.type = Blinds;
Obj.direction = Transition.IN;
Obj.duration = 4;
Obj.easing = Strong.easeIn;
Obj.numStrips = 10;
Obj.dimension = 1;

TransitionManager.start(picture_mc, Obj);
```

The thing is: I want to fade it back out right after it's done. I've tried looking this up, but there's on documentation to be found on it. Is there an event that is triggered, or do I need to set it myself?

Same thing goes for Tweens. No documentation at all.

Can someone explain, or link to a decent explanation. I'm using CS5/AS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use TweenMax for this sort of effect, one of the advantage being that it dispatches a complete event. Many Tweener classes do so though, so I would expect TransitionManager to do the same.
http://greensock.com

edit:
It actually does :) Check this article about undocumented features:
http://ducharme.cc/transitions-transition-manager/

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks. And for tweens, it's TweenEvent.MOTION_STOP

Answer (score 1):

For as3 you would use the TWEEN CLASS

Here is code that works:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween = new Tween(my_mc, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 100,300, 1, true);

myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void  { myTween.yoyo(); }
```